# Android: Disable button's transparency

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm making an app on Android and when I add a button with Eclipse's plugin the button is transparent.
For example:  
http://kakko76.free.fr/buttontransparent.png

But I don't want a transparent button!
I tried with background attribute on button but I losed the other effect on click or others.
How can I just disable button's transparency?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the button shouldn't be transparent. However you could just create a Selector for your Button, so you can set it as its background but still have a click-effect whenever you click it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="insert color"
                android:endColor="insert color"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="insert color" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:state_pressed="false" >        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="insert color"
                android:startColor="insert color"
               />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="insert color" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

These are the default images for the Button in API Level <10 :

**The selector:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_erase_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_erase_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_erase_default" />
</selector>
```

And the images you'll find in your

```
\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\  folder
```

e.g:

[image: pressed]
[image: default]
[image: selected]

Comment: the buttons in Ice Cream are transparent.

Comment: Thank you, it's work! But how can I found the default color already used for the default button?

Answer (score 1):

Found the perfect and simplest solution:

Just set the background of your button to

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
```

But make sure to do it directly in the XML,  not in the "Graphic Layout" interface because it probably won't work

Hope it saves someone's day ;)

Answer (score 0):

As i found the Ice-Cream resources, the button background image is transparent, so you need to change the background to your own image, using selectors.